# Java Generics. Сумма элементов коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, generics

Мне необходимо написать метод, который на вход принимает List, элементами которого являются все типы, наследуемые от Number, и возвращает сумму элементов этой коллекции.

```
 public static <T> Number test(List<? extends Number> myList)
    {
        Number result = 0;
        for (var element:
             myList)
        {
         result += element;
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что на строчке

```
result += element;
```

компилятор выдаёт ошибку

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Number', 'capture<? extends java.lang.Number>'
```

Как можно её обойти?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `<T>` - ?? *(нужно ещё 5 символов...)*

Comment: Ее нужно не обойти, а разобраться в том, как в Java организованы обощенные типы.

Comment: Ссылку нельзя перемещать, хотя значение ссылки может быть индекс массива. Также отсутствует перекрытие операторов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае проблема не в дженерике. Написать его в этом случае не составляет труда:

```
public static <T extends Number> T test(List<T> myList)
```

Проблема в том, что Number - абстрактный класс.
Представьте ситуацию.

`Number x = 3,5;` // На самом деле Java создает объект типа Double, являющийся наследником Number (double в упаковке)

`Number y = 4;` // То же самое здесь только создается Integer (int в упаковке)

И теперь делаем так: `Number z = x + y;`

В этом случае для Java все эти переменные типа абстрактного класса Number, в котором для извлечения данных разного типа предусмотрены разные методы (можете убедиться в этом, посмотрев сорцы). Тогда возникает справделивый вопрос: какой именно метод должен быть вызван автоматически для выполнения данной математической операции , учитывая, что этих самых методов много и правильный ответ на вопрос зависит от типа данных, приведенных к Number , соответсвенно , о нем ничего не известно (прошу не путать с полиморфизмом, где у разных наследников перопределен метод суперкласса, тогда сигнатура методов должна совпадать!).

Посему ответ звучит так:

1. Создание дженерика не вызывает никаких трудностей и я показал вам , как это сделать.
2. Java - язык со строгой типизацией, посему решить вашу задачу, разумеется можно, к примеру, с помощью instanceof , однако делать это на практике абсолютно бессмысленно и никогда не придется (за исключением свежепридуманных костылей)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, всё +- встало на свои места. Сейчас попробую закрепить парочкой статей